# How do I reduce two arrays to a single value that is present at the same index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have a D3 programme that is building a line chart where there are two lines and I want to ascertain the coordinates at where the lines cross . Does D3 have a function for this? The arrays are often of differing lengths and are dynamically generated, but will always have one value at which both will be equal at the same index.

e.g.

```
   var line1 = [0,1,2,3,4];
   var line2 = [4,3,2,1,0];
```

Answer = index 2, in this case. If there is no D3 function for this what would be the best approach using ES6 and above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3 has a quite unknown method, named [`d3.zip`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#zip), which we can use to merge the arrays and look for any inner array in which all the elements are equal:

```js
var line1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var line2 = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
var zip = d3.zip(line1, line2).reduce(function(a, c, i) {
  if (c[0] === c[1]) a.push(i);
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(zip)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The nice thing about `d3.zip` is that it can be used with several arrays, and also keeps the length of the shorter array. So, in a more complex case (equal values in the indices 6 and 9):

```js
var line1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 9, 1, 4, 7, 6, 5, 4];
var line2 = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 8, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1];
var line3 = [9, 9, 9, 9, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
var zip = d3.zip(line1, line2, line3).reduce(function(a, c, i) {
  const every = c.every(function(e) {
    return e === c[0]
  })
  if (every) a.push(i);
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(zip)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const [longer, shorter] = line1.length > line2.length ? [line1, line2] : [line2, line1];

const crossIndex = shorter.reduce((crossIndex, value, index) => {
  if (crossIndex !== null) {
    // already found it! just return
    return crossIndex;
  }

  // find it! return
  if (value === longer[index]) return index;

  // no found, continue searching
  return crossIndex;
}, null)
```

If you don't mind the search running a few extra useless iterations, the first step where we find out which line is longer or shorter, is actually not necessary. You call `.reduce()` on either line1 or line 2, then compare again the other, you'll still get the same result.